# Excessive inline warnings with intel compiler

Tags: c++, inline, icc

I am compiling an HPC code using the intel c++ compiler. There are several functions which must be inlined so I compile with the `-Winline` option to warn if they are not inlined correctly.

However, with `-Winline` turned on, there appear to be warnings generated for *every* function specified in the code that was not inlined, including those that were not specified as inline. I can remove the warning for individual functions by adding `__attribute__((noinline))` before the function, but I do not want to have to do this for every function in the code.

How do I tell the intel compiler to only provide warnings for functions which are specified as inline and have not been inlined?

Comment: I found that adding `-ipo` for interprocedural optimization did eliminate the error warnings and, ostensibly, improved performance.